# xul menulist bug with pydom

Tags: python, xul

i know pydom is deprecated .but my application already used this,this is so easy

my xul is like this.

```
<menulist name="mailencode" id="mailencode">
     <menupopup id="mailencodepop">
      <menuitem label="UTF-8" value="UTF-8" selected="true"/>
      <menuitem label="ISO-8859-1" value="ISO-8859-1" />
     </menupopup>
    </menulist>
```

in my python script

```
ecd=document.getElementById("mailencode")
print  ecd.selectedIndex
```

there is a exception,show me   XPCOM component '' has no attribute selectedIndex

i want get the use select value in the menulist

i also tired this,but the same exception

```
ecd=document.getElementById("mailencodepop")
print  ecd.selectedIndex
```

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that the tag name you're after is "menulist".  I used `xml.dom.minidom` to parse this just as a basic example to illustrate because I have never used PyDOM:

```
>>> ecd = document.getElementsByTagName('menulist')
[<DOM Element: menulist at 0x1006e2710>]
>>> ecd[0].tagName
u'menulist'
>>> ecd[0].attributes.items()
[(u'name', u'mailencode'), (u'id', u'mailencode')]
```

Then pull out the menulist tag on its own and then inspect its child nodes:

```
>>> menulist = ecd[0]
>>> menulist.childNodes
[<DOM Text node "u'\n     '">, <DOM Element: menupopup at 0x1006e29e0>, <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">]
```

And then inspect the `menupop` tag's child nodes:

```
>>> menulist.childNodes[1]
<DOM Element: menupopup at 0x1006e29e0>
>>> menulist.childNodes[1].childNodes
[<DOM Text node "u'\n      '">, <DOM Element: menuitem at 0x1006e2b90>, <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">, <DOM Element: menuitem at 0x1006e2ef0>, <DOM Text node "u'\n     '">]
```

There might be a better way, especially one using PyDOM. I just wanted to illustrate you need to be careful about the tag names you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The `selectedIndex` attribute is implemented through XBL, and I don't know whether pydom can talk to XBL. Can you call `QueryInterface` to expose the `nsIDOMXULMenuListElement` interface?